# Sitecore 8.0 Unexpected Datasource Output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

I am trying to show a table that contains a list of all items in a bucket. I've created the following ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Outage()
{
    if (IsDataSourceItemNull) return null;

    IEnumerable<SimpleItem> items = DataSourceItems.Select(x => new SimpleItem(x)).Where(x => SiteConfiguration.DoesItemExistInCurrentLanguage(x.Item));
    SimpleItemList results = new SimpleItemList(DataSourceItem["Title"], items);
    return !items.IsNullOrEmpty() ? View(results) : ShowListIsEmptyPageEditorAlert();
}
```

The code-behind for the controller rendering is this:

```
@model LaunchSitecore.Models.SimpleItemList

<div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.Sitecore().Field("Title")</td>
                    <td>@Html.Sitecore().Field("Date")</td>
                    <td>@Html.Sitecore().Field("Description")</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the model is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Sitecore.Mvc;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Links;
using LaunchSitecore.Configuration;

namespace LaunchSitecore.Models
{
    public class SimpleItemList
    {
        public string Title { get; protected set; }
        public IEnumerable<SimpleItem> Items { get; protected set; }

        public SimpleItemList(string title, IEnumerable<SimpleItem> items)
        {
          Title = title;
          Items = items;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this query as the data source in my rendering: 
[image: query]

[image: query results]

Finally, here is what I see on my page:

[image: final output]

I'm not sure why the title of my query is being returned...It is being generated the proper amount of times for how many "outage" items I have, but this obviously is not the desired output. I should see the data from the actual "outage" content items displayed in the table. Can anyone diagnose my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems if you don't supply the item *as well as* the field name, then it will look for that field on the **context item**, which is your query, I guess. So you can try supplying the `item` as well, like so:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Sitecore().Field("Title", item)</td>
        <td>@Html.Sitecore().Field("Date", item)</td>
        <td>@Html.Sitecore().Field("Description", item)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

More info here: [Rendering Content](http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/sitecore-mvc/rendering-content/).

Comment: Coolio, no problemo :-)